# Swift - UIPopoverController in iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller

I'm trying to add a simple popoverController to my iphone app, and I'm currently struggling with the classic "blank screen" which covers everything when I tap the button.

My code looks like this:

```
@IBAction func sendTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {


    var popView = PopViewController(nibName: "PopView", bundle: nil)

    var popController = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: popView)

    popController.popoverContentSize = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)

    popController.presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem(sendTappedOutl, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up, animated: true)

    func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController!) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        // Return no adaptive presentation style, use default presentation behaviour
        return .None
    }

}
```

The adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController-function was just something I added because I read somewhere that this is what you need to implement to get this function on the iphone. But still: there is still a blank image covering the whole screen, and I do not know how to fix it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution I implemented for this is based on an example presented in the 2014 WWDC session [View Controller Advancements in iOS 8](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#214) (see the [slide notes](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/214xxq2mdbtmp23/214/214_view_controller_advancements_in_ios_8.pdf)). Note that you do have to implement the `adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController` function as a part of the `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate`, but that function should be outside of your `sendTapped` function in your main view controller, and you must specify `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` in your class declaration line in that file to make sure that your code modifies that behaviour. I also took the liberty to separate out the logic to present a view controller in a popover into its own function and added a check to make sure the function does not present the request view controller if it is already presented in the current context.

So, your solution could look something like this:

```swift
// ViewController must implement UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate
class TheViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
    // ...
    // The contents of TheViewController class
    // ...

    @IBAction func sendTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let popView = PopViewController(nibName: "PopView", bundle: nil)
        self.presentViewControllerAsPopover(popView, barButtonItem: sender)
    }

    func presentViewControllerAsPopover(viewController: UIViewController, barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if let presentedVC = self.presentedViewController {
            if presentedVC.nibName == viewController.nibName {
                // The view is already being presented
                return
            }
        }
        // Specify presentation style first (makes the popoverPresentationController property available)
        viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
        let viewPresentationController = viewController.popoverPresentationController?
        if let presentationController = viewPresentationController {
            presentationController.delegate                 = self
            presentationController.barButtonItem            = barButtonItem
            presentationController.permittedArrowDirections = .Up
        }
        viewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)

        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .None
    }
}
```

#### Real world implementation

I implemented this approach for input validation on a sign up form in an in-progress app that I host on Github. I implemented it as extensions to `UIVIewController` in [`UIViewController+Extensions.swift`](https://github.com/acusti/photog/blob/master/Photog/UIViewController%2BExtensions.swift). You can see it in use in the validation functions in [`AuthViewController.swift`](https://github.com/acusti/photog/blob/master/Photog/AuthViewController.swift#L102). The [`presentAlertPopover` method](https://github.com/acusti/photog/blob/master/Photog/UIViewController%2BExtensions.swift#L29) takes a string and uses it to set the value of a UILabel in a `GenericAlertViewController` that I have set up (makes it easy to have dynamic text popovers). But the actual popover magic all happens in the [`presentViewControllerAsPopover` method](https://github.com/acusti/photog/blob/master/Photog/UIViewController%2BExtensions.swift#L39), which takes two parameters: the `UIViewController` instance to be presented, and a `UIView` object to use as the anchor from which to present the popover. The arrow direction is hardcoded as `UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up`, but that wouldn’t be hard to change.

Comment: @CliftonLabrum Yes, in fact. I’ll update my answer with that information.