# Show viewController swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uipopovercontroller, popover

I have a tableView and i made its cells custom and added a UIButton to the cell
i want when i press the button to popOver a new ViewController and in it the text in the cell i clicked the button in it. I don't want to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath func, i want to use the event of the button in each cell.

I tried to connect the button with the new viewController using popOver segue but the build fails because it is dynamic.

Please help and make the answer in swift. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show is the code of what you've tried?

Comment: Agree with @TimVermeulen, and sounds like you need to look into a delegate to tell your VC to do the segue.

Comment: @TimVermeulen : I didn't write any code because i don't know it is a new thing to me but i tried to make it from storyboard and ctr+drag from the button in the custom cell to new viewcontroller and chose popover as segue type and i got the error "Could'n compile connection". That's all

Comment: @sschale : When i add a static button i mean button that always there and ctr+drag from it to new viewcontroller everything going ok but when i do the same with the button in the cell it doesn't compile

Comment: i wanted to do it like the picture here gracefullycoded.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/screen1@3.5.jpeg 
but when i press a button in custom cell in tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouls set target to button inside the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath function

```
 cell.button.addTarget(self, action: "showPopupPage:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

create a function

```
  func showPopupPage(sender: UIButton) {
    let view = button.superview!
    let cell = view.superview as! custom cell
    // you can get cell contents here

 // call your popupview pass the value 
 }
```

Example=> 
[Swift - UIPopoverController in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670160/swift-uipopovercontroller-in-ios-8)

Comment: Thank you, it made me popover a viewController from my tableviewcell but i wanted it like the picture in this link:
http://gracefullycoded.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/screen1@3.5.jpeg
and instead of texts and labels i want to add mapview

Comment: To add mapView here is the example .http://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial

Comment: still have the same problem. i cant make a popover from the button in custom cell in tableview